# Node.js Express - app.all("*", func) doesn't get called when visiting root domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to set a global function that is called on every page load, regardless of its location in my website. As per Express's API, I've used

```
app.all("*", doSomething);
```

to call the function doSomething on every page load, but it doesn't completely work. The function fires on every page load, except for page loads of the base domain (e.g. http://domain.com/pageA will call the function, but http://domain.com won't). Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Plato's answer is mostly likely the solution to your problem. But if it is not, then for situations like these posting the code relevant to demonstrate the issue is necessary in order for us to offer a proper solution. Please post a more complete example of your route definitions if your issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 8):

I bet that you placed

```
app.get('/', fn)
```

above

```
app.all("*", doSomething);
```

Remember that Express will execute middleware functions in the order they are registered until something sends a response

Answer (score 8):

I know that's an old one, but still maybe useful to someone.

I think the problem could be:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var router = express.Router();

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("middleware");
    next();
});

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('root');
});
router.get('/anything', function(req, res) {
   console.log('any other path');
});
```

where is middleware invoked on any path, but `/`

It happens because express.static by default serves `public/index.html` on `/`

To solve it add parameter to the static middleware:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
    index: false
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run some code on every request, you don't need to use the router.

Simply place a middleware above the router, and it will be called on every request:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  //whatever you put here will be executed
  //on each request

  next();  // BE SURE TO CALL next() !!
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Where is app.all('*') in the chain? If its after all the other routes, it might not be invoked.

```
app.post("/something",function(req,res,next){ ...dothings.... res.send(200); });

app.all('*',function(req,res) { ...this NEVER gets called. No next and res already sent });
```

Unless it was your intention to have it be last, in which case you have to be sure to call next() in the preceeding routes. For example:

```
app.post("/something",function(req,res,next){ ...dothings.... next();});

app.all('*',function(req,res) { ...this gets called });
```

Also, what's in doSomething? Are you sure its not getting called?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and I discovered that the number of arguments your `doSomething` function have might be a factor.

```
function doSomething(req, res, next) {
    console.log('this will work');
}
```

whereas:

```
function doSomething(req, res, next, myOwnArgument) {
    console.log('this will never work');
}
```

Comment: I believe this is because Express interprets 4-ary handlers as error handlers with signature `function handle(err, req, res, next){` and I think the whole error handling chain gets invoked if you do `next(err)` from a previous handler or middleware